# Подсчитать количество строк

Tags: sql, sql-server

Объясните, пожалуйста, как найти самую частую строку в таблице или просто подсчитать частоту каждой строки. В данном случае `'Peter'`, без использования циклов и редких выражений. В основном надо использовать что-то из этого (`having`, `top`, `group`, `order`, `count`, `max`, `sum`, `in`)

```
CREATE TABLE t(n nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO  t (n) VALUES
('Andrey'),('Alexey'),('Ivan'),('Peter'),('Ivan'),
('Peter'),('Ivan'),('Peter'),('Misha'),('Peter')
```

Не подходит, т.к. цифра `1` задана вручную

```
SELECT n 
FROM  t  
group by n 
HAVING Count(n)>1
```

Не подходит, т.к. ошибка в построении типов

```
select n
from (select n from (select n from t group by n) order by id)
having max (count(n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам надо группировать по имени и считать количество. потом по этому количеству отсортировать и взять только первый результат.

```
 SELECT TOP 1 n
 FROM t
 GROUP BY n
 ORDER BY count(n) DESC
```